# How to remove BarItemColor & SelectedBarItemColor in TabbedPage-BottomNavigation Bar in Xamarin.Forms- Android?

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbedpage, android-bottomnavigationview

I have changed the Xamarin.Forms TabbedPage's BottomNavigation Bar's (android) Selected Tab's icon with a `CustomRenderer` to a multi colored version of the icon that appears when not selected. But because of there is a default `SelectedBarItemColor` for that icon, it takes `SelectedBarItemColor` instead of it's original color. How can I keep the icon's original color and get rid of that `SelectedBarItemColor` ?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if it is similar to an issue I ran to before, but what i had was that the styles.axml (or w.e it is called)for android overrode my color choices for a switch control. What I had to do was create my own separate style.xaml page for that control and apply it to my switch. Perhaps that is a similar approach you might need to try?

Comment: If you have svg icons you can use `UnselectedTabColor` and  `SelectedTabColor` properties from the `TabbedPage` to asign selected and unselected colors, instead doing a custom renderer.

Answer (score 1):

I could fix this issue by adding below line in my CustomRenderer

```
bottomNavigationView.ItemIconTintList = null;
```